# How to disable DNS caching on Windows Server 2008

Tags: wcf, amazon-web-services, dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running into an issue with DNS caching whilst running a test application on a Windows Server 2008 environment. The test application simulates hundreds of users connection to a web service. The web service is hosted behind Amazons Web Services and is actually a load balancer with many Amazon EC2 instances behind it. The load balancer and EC2 instances work fine under normal operation as the normal client connections distribute evenly. However, when I run the test application, all the connections hit a single EC2 instance. I believe this may be down to the Windows environment hosting the test application caching the DNS lookup.

How can I disable DNS caching? I thought it would be easy by just stopping the DNS Client service (as mentioned here: http://www.tipsandtutorials.net/how-to-turn-off-dns-caching-under-microsoft-windows.html) but this did not change anything. Is there anything else that must be done to disable the caching?

Is there something else I could look at which might be causing these problem?

**EDIT:** Is it possible there is another level of DNS caching within the WCF service that is being used?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your load balancer is trying to send all traffic from the same host to the same server... this is "by design"... (aka: "sticky session")

You need to explicitly tell your load balancer that you want to disable sticky sessions and enable "round robin"... (the specific terminology will vary depending on your load balancer technology)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think this is the case as running a local console application with the DNS Client service on the local machine turned off seems to spread load correctly. It is only when we use the test application which uses WCF services that load balancing doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277702/1077279), I think you need

```
ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
```

and

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

You can set the `ServicePointManager` settings via the web.config. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsk61s76.aspx).

Also, there's another similar setting `enableDnsRoundRobin` which looks like it might help you too.