# Which IP does .NET HttpWebRequest use if DNS entry is bound to multiple addresses

Tags: .net, dns, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm using a System.Net.HttpWebRequest to hit an API application hosted within AWS behind a load-balancer.  The LB has 6 instances, 3 in 2 different AZs.  As a result, the DNS entry for the LB has 2 IP Addresses (1 for each AZ).

When I run my C# app, the web requests appear to be balanced perfectly between 3 servers within a single AZ.  It's not hitting the 2nd AZ.

It seems to me that the WebRequest object is only ever hitting the 1st IP that is bound to the LB DNS entry, which is why traffic is balanced, but only in a single AZ.

Does that make sense?  How do I get the WebRequest to target other IPs bounds to a DNS entry?

Comment: What is a C# WebRequest? Do you mean the .NET WebRequest class?

Comment: @JohnSaunders System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Comment: What's that have to do with C#? That's a ".NET WebRequest", or maybe a "System.Net.WebRequest".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was trying to be clear.  I changed the tag to .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpWebRequest always uses the first IP address in the list.  Route53 returns the IP addresses from a single loadbalancer in a random order which help balance the load across the AZs.

Answer (score 0):

When C# does a DNS lookup (via .NET) it'll cache that result. This means that it will continue using whatever IP it gets back first.

Take a look at [How do I clear System.Net client DNS cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277582/how-do-i-clear-system-net-client-dns-cache) -- this might steer you in the right direction.

Comment: .NET DNS lookup returns 2 IP addresses, for a single DNS hostname.  I'm asking how C# determines which IP address to use.

Comment: C# never uses DNS, under any circumstances. It has no network support. Maybe you are referring to .NET?

Comment: Sorry, yes: the .NET framework lookup that the C# call is going to trigger. I believe the answer around clearing the System.Net DNS cache stands.

Comment: Almost there - would this be identical for a VB.NET application?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have run into one of the weaknesses of the the AWS ELB. All requests from a single IP will get routed to one AZ. This makes the elb problematic for web services that have alot of traffic but only from a small ip subset.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.  When you perform a DNS request on the ELB's address it returns the IP addresses in random order (even if you make the DNS request from the same client IP numerous times).