# Does .Net Respect DNS TTL Values

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I'm having a hard time finding information about whether or not .Net (C# specifically if it matters) respects the TTL values for DNS entries. I believe it **does not** based on the information I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277582/how-do-i-clear-system-net-client-dns-cache). I noticed in other places that Java also does not respect DNS TTL values ([Any way to make Java honor the DNS Caching Timeout (TTL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl)). Am I right that the only way to control how long a DNS lookup is cached is by using the `ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout` property? If this is a case does anyone have information on why this is the case? Seems like a non-obvious choice for programming languages.

Comment: The [Dns Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) just calls into the Win32 API, so the question is if Windows respects TTL values/caches DNS information. ServicePointManager is used (afaik) only by HttpWebRequest; it uses the Dns class (which does not expose TTL information) to make a lookup, and caches the result for DnsRefreshTimeout.