# Under what condition will HttpWebRequest recognize DNS change?

Tags: c#, dns, httpwebrequest, ttl, system.net.httpwebrequest

We have multiple remote services which are sending files up to a central server. The code for the file upload is presented below.

We need to switch our server; for this discussion let's say we are switching from CurrServer to NewServer. https://upload.domain.com (a hypothetical URL) is currently pointing to CurrServer.

I have two processes running. One process is monitoring a local file folder. When a file materializes in that folder it uploads the file to CurrServer. The second process is popping test files into that folder location. Every 30 seconds it pops a file into the monitored folder and a few milliseconds later that file is uploaded to CurrServer.

Now I switch the DNS for upload.domain.com to point to NewServer. However, files continue to arrive at CurrServer. Not what I want to see, because we have hundreds of these widely distributed remote uploader processes. I need these to adjust automatically to the new DNS setting, otherwise I will be scrambling to restart these services at hundreds of remote locations.

I stopped the process which pops the test files into the monitored folder. I did NOT stop the uploader process, this merely gives it 'a rest'. About 5 minutes later I restarted the process and observed files flowing to NewServer, as desired. OK, that's good. But what is going on here?

Through trial and error I can see that if my interval between file uploads is 2 minutes or greater, the uploader process adjusts to the new DNS. If the interval is less than 2 minutes though, the uploader does not recognize the DNS change. (FYI - in anticipation of the migration, TTL on this DNS A record is at 2 mins. Is this relevant?) Based on my observations, it seems as though there is some underlying cache so that an instance of HttpWebRequest for a given URL will use the same IP address as a previous instance for the same url, without doing a DNS lookup. Is this correct? Is this documented? Can you give me the reference? Also, in my experiments, the original web server remains active, accepting connections and uploads. Is there a specific Http status which I can return which will inform the client that the current connection is no longer valid in order to cause the client to do a new DNS lookup?

Also, is there any way that I can re-engineer my method so that a DNS lookup will be done on every file upload? Would that be a bad idea performance-wise? (While the current situation is throwing a wrinkle into my migration plans, it's not every day we do such a migration.)

```
    public static bool PushFile(string url, string user, string pass, string filePath, int transferRate, bool httpPut = true)
    {
        long fileLength = 0;
        bool stat = false;
        bool error = false;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        HttpStatusCode httpStatus = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;

        try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
            fileLength = fi.Length;

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            if (httpPut == true)
            {
                webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
            }
            else
            {
                webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            }
            webRequest.ContentLength = fileLength;
            webRequest.SendChunked = true;
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Translate: f");
            webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

            Stream webStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[transferRate - 1];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                webStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            webStream.Close();
            webStream.Dispose();
            webStream = null;

            fileStream.Close();
            fileStream.Dispose();
            fileStream = null;

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            httpStatus = webResponse.StatusCode;

            webResponse.Close();
            webResponse.Dispose();
            webResponse = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (error == false && totalBytesRead == fileLength && ((httpPut == true && httpStatus == HttpStatusCode.Created) || (httpPut == false && httpStatus == HttpStatusCode.OK)))
            {
                stat = true;
            }
        }

        return stat;
    }
```

Comment: "Would that be a bad idea performance-wise?" It certainly would be. DNS data is supposed to be cached for "some time" and you can adjust that by putting appropriate time in the TTL field of each record.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Right now I have TTL at 2 minutes in anticipation of the impending change. So how come HttpWebRequest is holding onto the DNS info for hours? Only if the process stops sending files for at least two minutes does HttpWebRequest recognize the reconfigured DNS info. Is that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: "So how come HttpWebRequest is holding onto the DNS info for hours?" You need to check its documentation, I am sorry I know nothing about C# but I know for example that in Java, by default, the name resolution is done only once (when it is needed) and reused later for the whole life of the program (so in that case things will not see a record change at the DNS level). I guess you are in the same kind of cases in C# for this library. Typically program asks OS to do name resolution but may then keep the result. Only if a DNS resolution is forced again, then the TTL will be honoured.

Comment: This may help but is old: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454925/does-net-respect-dns-ttl-values or this https://www.nimaara.com/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/ "A Singleton HttpClient does not respect DNS changes!" as I understand HttpClient is an higher interface that HttpWebRequest so it may inherit its problems.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Thank you for that link -  https://www.nimaara.com/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/. Money quote: ...well all the DNS entries are cached which by default does not refresh for 2 minutes. Yes! this is exactly what I am seeing. If my conenction is idle for two minutes or more then it does honor the DNS change on the next connection. Follow-up question - is there an HttpStatus which I can return for requests to the old server which will instruct the client - close your connection and refresh DNS, because I am no longer valid? Thanks!

Comment: "is there an HttpStatus which I can return for requests to the old server which will instruct the client - close your connection and refresh DNS" No, not that I am aware of.