# System.net.HTTPClient ignore C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Tags: windows, winapi, httpclient

I have a strange problem: `System.net.HTTPClient` seems to ignore hostname settings in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`..

**steps to reproduce..**

**1** Map a hostname on a local ipaddress in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, eg.:

```
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

**2** flush the dns cache with a console command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

**3** ping the hostname `www.google.com` and check if it resolves to `127.0.0.1` (**works for me**):

```
ping www.google.com
```

**4** make a request with `System.net.HTTPClient` (I use Delphi);

```
aFileStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\response.html', fmCreate);
aHTTPClient := THTTPClient.create;
try
    aHTTPClient.Get('http://www.google.com/', aFileStream);
finally
    aHTTPClient.free;
    aFileStream.free;
end;
```

`HTTPClient` returns the real `www.google.com` page but if I open Internet Explorer and type www.google.com I see my local server.

Why does the `HTTPClient` not follow the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` setting?

Comment: I am working with httpclient as we speak and using HOSTS to test bits & bobs and it behaves exactly as it should (i.e. honouring entries) - are you behind a proxy server of some kind?

Comment: @AlexK. httpclients seems has a own dns cache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277582/how-do-i-clear-system-net-client-dns-cache?rq=1