# How do I disable keep-alive for a basicHttpRelayBinding to the Azure service bus?

Tags: c#, wcf, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm trying to disable HTTP `keep-alive`, and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to achieve that.  Ultimately, I am occasionally getting:

> **System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException**: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

I've heard the best approach is simply to disable HTTP `keep-alive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I solved my own issue here with a little helper function that takes my basicHttpRelayBinding and modifies it appropriately:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBinding(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding bIn)
    {
        var bOut = new CustomBinding(bIn);
        var transportElement = bOut.Elements
              .Find<HttpsRelayTransportBindingElement>();
        transportElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
        return bOut;
    }
```

Comment: See [related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6535452/175679) for similar non-Azure solution.